# Reduce weights for wrongly predicted class

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm currently working on a simple prediction system, where the user is asked a series of yes/no questions and based on their responses, a pre-trained model (MLPClassifier) predicted a class and asks the user whether or not the prediction was right. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I was hoping to then alter the weights of the pre-trained model (in sort of an online-learning fashion) so that the network (in that session) doesn't predict the same class later. Currently, I'm just adding the bad responses to a dictionary and if the network predicts the class already in the black-listed set of classes it is ignored however I feel there must be a better approach than this! My code for the classifier is:

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(128,), max_iter=500, alpha=1e-4,
                    solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                    learning_rate_init=.1, )
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.values[:, 0:8], df.label_idx, test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=42)
```

And the code for the predictions is:

```
def receive_input():
responses = []
bad_guesses = []
print("Answer questions (Yes/No) or enter END to make prediction")
count = 0
while count < len(questions):
    print(questions[count])
    response = input().lower().strip()
    if response == 'end':
        break
    elif response == 'yes':
        responses.append(1)
    elif response == 'no':
        responses.append(0)
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')
        continue
    count += 1

    padded_responses = np.pad(np.array(responses), (0, 8 - len(responses)), 'constant', constant_values=(0, -1))
    prob_pred = mlp.predict_proba(padded_responses.reshape(1, -1)).flatten()
    index = np.argmax(prob_pred)
    best_score = prob_pred[index]
    guess = labels[index]
    if best_score > 0.8 and guess not in bad_guesses:
        print('Early guess is: ' + labels[index] + ' is this right ? (Yes/No)')
        correct = input()
        if correct == 'Yes':
            break
        elif correct == 'No':
            bad_guesses.append(labels[index])

pred = mlp.predict(np.array(responses).reshape(1, -1))
print('Prediction is: ' + labels[pred[0]])
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks to work, thank you

Comment: Yeah sounds good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mlp.coefs_` gives you a list, in which the `ith` element represents the ***weight matrix*** corresponding to layer `i`.

Moreover, `mlp.intercepts_` gives you a list, in which the `ith` element represents the ***bias vector*** corresponding to layer `i + 1`.

So you can try and see if these attributes are alterable.